# How to get same size column in bootstrap in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Please Don't Consider this as duplicate question as the methods provided in similar question does't seems to be working.**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=407%C3%97832&w=407&h=832" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 16 GB)</h4>
          <p>500</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=78&txt=832%C3%97562&w=832&h=562" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)</h4>
          <p>350</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=40&txt=424%C3%97832&w=424&h=832" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Redmi Note 3 (Dark Grey, 16 GB)</h4>
          <p>50</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=78&txt=832%C3%97539&w=832&h=539" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>HP Pavilion Celeron Dual Core - (2 GB/500 GB HDD/DOS) W0H99PA 11-S003TU Notebook  (11.6 inch, Black, 1.23 kg)</h4>
          <p>350</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**I am trying to get the outside box of same dimensions.**

**Please See the Output in fullscreen to understand.**

I can't add custom class and style to each div col because there is only 1 div that is looping in foreach i.e data is coming from database.

I have applied `style="max-height:242px; width: auto;"` to images so they contain similar size. but the problem is when text is more.

**Please tell me know how to get same size box so that even if more text is there the box stays same size.**

Thanks!

Comment: How can the box remain the same when there is more text? It has to increase in size. What if you limit the characters? Is that a chance?

Comment: That would be the last thing to do as I wanted to show full title. Is there a way with javascript to find the largest div and set others to its size.

Comment: Yes now that's a possibility :) Adding my answer

Comment: You can use flex if you are not targeting all browsers. There is another jquery script https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height which might be helpful.

Comment: thanks will look at this option also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.fx-container,
.fx-container > div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row  fx-container">    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=407%C3%97832&w=407&h=832" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 16 GB)</h4>
          <p>500</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=78&txt=832%C3%97562&w=832&h=562" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)</h4>
          <p>350</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=40&txt=424%C3%97832&w=424&h=832" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Redmi Note 3 (Dark Grey, 16 GB)</h4>
          <p>50</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" >        
      <div class="thumbnail">            
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=78&txt=832%C3%97539&w=832&h=539" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>HP Pavilion Celeron Dual Core - (2 GB/500 GB HDD/DOS) W0H99PA 11-S003TU Notebook  (11.6 inch, Black, 1.23 kg)</h4>
          <p>350</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can use `Flexbox` for that. This is the minimal that can be used, you can add more style as per your need.

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Glad it helps you :)

Comment: This will keep the columns unresponsive!

Comment: For that media queries can be used as-per need. This is general solution.

Comment: Is there a way to make button align with each other from bottom so it looks nice.

Comment: can you also please tell how to make it resposive.

Comment: Use position:relative on parent element, and position:absolute on chile element and then bottom:0 to chile element

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't let me mark this answer as my reputation is less that 15.

Comment: For media queries, refer this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Use flex for row:

However, it will render the .row unresponsive, so add the `display:flex` inside a media query:

Go full page for equal height columns

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  [class*=col-sm-] .thumbnail {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=407%C3%97832&w=407&h=832" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Apple iPhone 6 (Space Grey, 16 GB)</h4>
          <p>500</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=78&txt=832%C3%97562&w=832&h=562" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)</h4>
          <p>350</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=40&txt=424%C3%97832&w=424&h=832" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Redmi Note 3 (Dark Grey, 16 GB)</h4>
          <p>50</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=78&txt=832%C3%97539&w=832&h=539" alt="thumb01" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:242px; width: auto;">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>HP Pavilion Celeron Dual Core - (2 GB/500 GB HDD/DOS) W0H99PA 11-S003TU Notebook  (11.6 inch, Black, 1.23 kg)</h4>
          <p>350</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View Product</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

use below style

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex; 
}
.col-sm-6.col-md-3 {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

this is just style: you should add and use different class names

Comment: You should be more specific about your answer.

Comment: I tried but its not doing what I wanted. Can do a snippet where I can see the output as the box are not of same dimensions by using about style